# Ошибка до нажатия кнопки submit

Tags: php

Есть задание

> Напишите скрипт, который по введенному числу K, выводит на экран фразу "В корзине K товаров", причем согласовывает окончание слова "товар" с числом K (например, "В корзине 1 товар" или "В корзине 4 товара")

Я написал код, все работает.
Вот только проблема, так как у меня форма и скрипт на одной странице, как только я запускаю ее и пока не введено первое значение, мне выдает ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined index: k in `C:\www\htdocs\1hw.php` on line 31

Вот моя 31я строка:

```
$k=$_POST["k"];
```

То есть он пытается взять значение, которое еще не введено.
После первого нажатия на кнопку submit все работает отлично, ошибка уходит.
Как мне устранить ее до первого нажатия?

Answer (score 2):

Проверяйте "прилетела ли" глобальная переменная:

```
if(isset($_POST["k"])){
    $k=$_POST["k"];
    // что-то делаем
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло

Answer (score 0):

а проще так

```
$k = isset($_POST["k"]) ? $_POST["k"] : null;
```